# PHP: Best solution for links breaking in a mod_rewrite app

Tags: php, apache, design-patterns, mod-rewrite

I'm using mod rewrite to redirect all requests targeting non-existent files/directories to `index.php?url=*`

This is surely the most common thing you do with mod_rewrite yet I have a problem:

Naturally, if the page url is "mydomain.com/blog/view/1", the browser will look for images, stylesheets and relative links in the "virtual" directory "mydomain.com/blog/view/".

**Problem 1:**

- Is using the base tag the best solution? I see that none of the PHP frameworks out there use the base tag, though.
- I'm currently having a regex replace all the relative links to point to the right path before output. Is that "okay"?

**Problem 2:**

It is possible that the server doesn't support mod_rewrite. However, all public files like images, stylesheets and the requests collector index.php are located in the directory `/myapp/public`. Normally mod_rewrite points all request to `/public` so it seems as if public was actually the root directory too all users.

However if there is no mod_rewrite, I then have to point the users to `/public` from the root directory with a `header()` call. That means, however that all links are broken again because suddenly all images, etc. have to be called via `/public/myimage.jpg`

Additional info: When there is no mod_rewrite the above request would look like this: `mydomain.com/public/index.php/blog/view/1`

- What would be the best solutions for both problems?

**Edit/Additional question:**

Is there a way to make /public/ the base dir using plain htaccess code?

Answer (score 2):

Write the app in such a way that it doesn't need mod_rewrite to function (at the cost of having "ugly" urls). Progressively enhance it with mod_rewrite to achieve the desired result.  This probably means that you'll need to store some base path config info in your app.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand these problems at all.
Yes, this is surely the most common thing you do with mod_rewrite, **yet** with 2 conditions:

```
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

So, nothing hurt your existing images.

Why not to use just **absolute path**, e.g. `/myapp/public/myimage.jpg`, so, no virtual directory will hurt image path?

Comment: I think you don't understand the question at all.

Comment: @psil I think quite contrary. You devised your problems out of nowhere. You're doing usual thing unusual way. Why not to use plain and simple solutions?

Answer (score 0):

what about path info? You could use it without mod_rewrite

/index.php/path/to/another/file.jpg

```
<?php
echo $_SERVER["PATH_INFO"]; // outputs /path/to/another/file.jpg
?>
```

Anyways, if you want to know if mod_rewrite is supported by your server :

```
<?php
echo "mod_rewrite : ".(!empty($_SERVER["REDIRECT_URL"])?"supported":"not supported");
?>
```

Then you ll know if mod_rewrite is the solution or maybe path_info is more well suited for you, you could make support functions that could look for both too.